# Condition check inside a function or before its call?

Tags: coding-style

Which of these 2 programming styles do you prefer? Why? Are there particular advantages to one over the other?

```
// Style 1
if (doBorder)
    doTheBorder();
if (doFrame)
    doTheFrame();
if (doDraw)
    doTheDraw();

void doTheBorder()
{
  // ...
}

void doTheFrame()
{
  // ...
}

void doTheDraw()
{
  // ...
}

// Style 2
doTheBorder();
doTheFrame();
doTheDraw();

void doTheBorder()
{
  if (!doBorder)
    return;
  // ...
}

void doTheFrame()
{
  if (!doFrame)
    return;
  // ...
}

void doTheDraw()
{
  if (!doDraw)
    return;
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first. The second seems to be... lacking in confidence. Why call `doTheBorder()` if you don't even know if you want the border to be done? IMO, you should assert that the border *really needs* doing, and *then* call `doTheBorder()` with confidence!

...Also, from a more technical point of view: if `doTheBorder()` is in a closed API, a developer in the distant future might call it and if the second style is employed, they may wonder why the border didn't get done, despite their call to `doTheBorder()`. Of course, sometimes certain circumstances or restrictions or limitations may dictate that the second style be used, but I'd avoid it when possible.